# Images not stacking up in Masonry template?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-masonry

So apparently my images are not stacking up on top of each other.  They are all in straight horizontal rows.  Not sure what is wrong.  I want the images to be stacked up on top of each other in a fitted Pinterest-like/Masonry grid.

Here's the shortcode I use in my index file:

```
  echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id="1"]');
```

Here's the code found in my Masonry gallery template file:

```
  <?php
  /**
  Template Page for the gallery overview
  Follow variables are useable :
  $gallery : Contain all about the gallery
   $images : Contain all images, path, title
   $pagination : Contain the pagination content
  You can check the content when you insert the tag <?php var_dump($variable) ?>
   If you would like to show the timestamp of the image ,you can use <?php echo $exif['created_timestamp'] ?>
  **/
  ?>
   <script src="/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
   <script>
  $(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
itemSelector : '.box'
    });
  });

  });
   </script>
  <style>
  .brick {
  display: block;
   margin: 0px 10px 15px 10px;
   float:left;
  /* width:250px; */
   height: auto;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
   jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
   $('#wall').masonry({
   // options
   itemSelector : '.brick',
  isAnimated: true,
   animationOptions: {
   duration: 500,
   easing: 'linear',
   queue: false}
   });
  </script>
  <?php if (!defined ('ABSPATH')) die ('No direct access allowed'); ?><?php if (!empty ($gallery)) : ?>
  <div class="ngg-galleryoverview" id="<?php echo $gallery->anchor ?>">
  <div id="wall">
  <!-- Thumbnails -->
<?php $i = 0; ?>
  <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>
  <div class="brick">
  <a class="thickbox" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
  <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
  <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
  <?php } ?>
  </a>
  </div>
  <?php if ( $image->hidden ) continue; ?>
     <?php if ($gallery->columns > 0): ?>
    <?php if ((($i + 1) % $gallery->columns) == 0 ): ?>
        <br style="clear: both" />
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php echo $pagination ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This is what my gallery looks like on the actual page:

http://steppic.com/original/896e07bdf2f759709b9ccc5f9eea9e28.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling masonry twice with different parameters.

The first, your container is "#container" and your items are ".box":

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.masonry({
itemSelector : '.box'
});
```

In the second, your container is "#wall" and your items are ".brick", and you left out "});" at the end of your (document).ready

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
 $('#wall').masonry({
 // options
 itemSelector : '.brick',
isAnimated: true,
 animationOptions: {
 duration: 500,
 easing: 'linear',
 queue: false}
 });
 }); //this was missing
```

Pick the correct container and items and it should work

Comment: Ok, I removed the first one that had #container and then fixed the missing "});" on the second container but the gallery images are still not stacked up.  Still in rows.

Comment: Two questions. Is jQuery loaded and is the class of your images .brick?

Comment: how do I know if the jQuery is loaded or not? and yes, my images are under a div class called ".brick".

Comment: I took the <script> codes which called for the js file and jquery and removed them from the template and inserted them into the bottom of he footer.php file right before wp_footer but nothing seems to have changed/ http://funnykittenmemes.com/

Comment: You are not loading masonry. Your masonry.js file is some sort of masonry shim script, not the actual masonry.pkgd.min.js [Download it here](http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js). Install the actual script and it should work

Comment: The guy who created the file messaged me on Skype (I added him) and he sent me the original file and I uploaded it and it works now but the pagination disappeared.  Trying to get pagination working.  Also, I have no idea how to unpackage a pkgd file which the file that you linked to was in.

Comment: You don't unpackage the file, it is just how the script is compressed to reduce its size.

Comment: AH ok gotcha.  Well any ways, it works now except I'm trying to figure out how to make the pagination work.  The navigation bar shows up but the actual pages don't.  Eg: http://funnykittenmemes.com/2014/10/hello-world/nggallery/page/2  According to the guy who sent me the masonry js file (unpackaged), permalinks is a known problem for nextgen.  but I wonder how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like another question. Please accept my answer if you feel it was correct. Thanks

Comment: haha good point though the guy who was helping me on Skype was telling me to do some research on google because other people had the same problem with permalink/pagination.  but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure as I don't know if you provided the complete CSS, but maybe it will work if you just remove the `margin: 0px 10px 15px 10px;` for class `brick`.
On the masonry example page I just adjusted an example by adding this margin to the class `item` which corresponds to your class `brick`, and the result looks similar to your screenshot: 
[Masonry Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJmDk)

In addition, it looks like you call masonry twice - one time for `.container` -   `$container.masonry({...`, and a second time for `#wall` - `$('#wall').masonry({...`
You could check if it's working like intended when you remove the margin as suggested and maybe also call masonry only once.

**Update:**  Next adjustment you can try is to remove `height: auto;` from class `brick`. 
I've adjusted a masonry example by adding height: auto to class item: [Masonry with height: auto](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzpCv), as you will notice, there are some issues not present when the setting for height is removed: [Masonry without height: auto](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AGicy)

For masonry reference: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Comment: When I comment out the margin, the images don't stack up.  The images on each row just move in close to each other so that there is no gap between them.  The gaps between each row also closes in.  But the images do not stack up.  The rows and columns just move closer to each other.  Still looks like a table but with no margin.

As for the masonry getting called twice, which one should I comment out?  The container or the wall?

Comment: Also, my other CSS properties:

`.ngg-galleryoverview {
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
display: block !important;`  That's the only other one I saw.  I have an id called "wall" and class called "thickbox" in the code but they are not in the actual css file.

Comment: i'll look into the update you posted but the other guy's answer helped me out a lot.